# Est-il préférable d’employer « à » ou « dans » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

Au début, seule mon oreille gauche était infectée et bouchée puis au fil des heures l’infection s’est propagée à/dans l’oreille droite.

Autre tournure plus simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La préposition habituelle dans ce contexte est **à** :

> *La sensation de plénitude est probablement due à une accumulation de liquide dans l'oreille moyenne parce que l'infection des voies respiratoires supérieures (rhume) s'est propagée à l'oreille.*
> Elaine Marieb, Katja Hoehn, *Anatomie et physiologie humaines*, 2014

> *Otite externe maligne propagée à l'oreille interne : très visible.*
> Axel Ellrodt, *Urgences médicales*, 2017

« Se propager **dans** » n'implique pas une provenance externe : une infection peut naître dans un organe et se propager **dans** celui-ci alors que « Se propager **à** » indique clairement le déplacement effectué d'un endroit à un autre.

Comment: Souvent quand je pose une question sur cette plateforme, je reçois des réponses contradictoires. C’est bon d’avoir différents points de vue sur une question et c’est encore mieux lorsqu’ils reposent sur des arguments convaincants ou des explications satisfaisantes, comme c’est le cas ici, qui permettent de trancher une bonne fois pour toutes.

Answer (score 1):

J'utiliserais `dans` avec `aussi`:
... l’infection s’est propagée aussi dans l’oreille droite.

- Ses idées se sont propagées dans les milieux intellectuels.
- Propager une nouvelle dans la population.

Si j'utilise `à`, je dis:
... l’infection est passée à l’oreille droite.

Comment: Je trouve personnellement _s’est propagée aussi_ bancal, je dirais plutôt _s’est aussi propagée_.